# Bash update image value in yaml file

Tags: linux, bash, yaml

I have a yaml file and need to update the value of the image key. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried different solutions but none have given the expected output. Thanks in advance

**yaml**

```
global:
environment:
   - license_key: uasd89ys8dashlkas
   services:
      tracking-service:
         image: mmg.idom.tracking-1.3.0.jar #<= I need the change ONLY this value under tracking-service
         route_path: "/tracking/**"
         environment:
           - LOGGING_FILE: /dev/gtm/logs/tracking-service/tracking-service.log
         mem_limit: 384m
         restart: always
         health_endpoint: /tracking/health

      location-mobile-health:
         image: mmg.ips.location-1.4.6.jar
         route_path: "/location-mobile/**"
         environment:
          - LOGGING_FILE: /dev/gtm/logs/location-mobile-health/location-mobile-health.log
         mem_limit: 128m
         restart: always
```

**What I tried:**

```
sed -i -e "/^tracking-service:/,/image:/{/^\([[:space:]]*image: \).*/s//\$NewValue/}" \test.yaml
```

**Expected output**

```
global:
environment:
   - license_key: uasd89ys8dashlkas
   services:
      tracking-service:
         image: NEW-value.jar #<= I need the change ONLY this value under tracking-service
         route_path: "/tracking/**"
         environment:
           - LOGGING_FILE: /dev/gtm/logs/tracking-service/tracking-service.log
         mem_limit: 384m
         restart: always
         health_endpoint: /tracking/health

      location-mobile-health:
         image: mmg.ips.location-1.4.6.jar
         route_path: "/location-mobile/**"
         environment:
          - LOGGING_FILE: /dev/gtm/logs/location-mobile-health/location-mobile-health.log
         mem_limit: 128m
         restart: always
```

Comment: The _Right Way_ to do this involves using a YAML-aware tool such as `yq`. Using structure-unaware tools to edit structured data generally is not a thing that ends well -- it can look like it works with your sample inputs, but it very rarely works properly for all possible values that your file can contain, all values you might want to substitute, etc.

Comment: I dont want to use any tools I have to download. I need to use core tools as this code will run on a prod server. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Are you aware that YAML is a superset of JSON? If you change your file format to be in the JSON subset there are plenty of tools installed by default that can edit it correctly, including the Python standard library (if your servers aren't running an OS new enough to ship jq by default, which many do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ newValue="NEW-value.jar"
$ sed -E "/tracking-service/{n;s~(image: ).*~\1$newValue~}" input_file
global:
environment:
   - license_key: uasd89ys8dashlkas
   services:
      tracking-service:
         image: NEW-value.jar
         route_path: /tracking/**
         environment:
           - LOGGING_FILE: /dev/gtm/logs/tracking-service/tracking-service.log
         mem_limit: 384m
         restart: always
         health_endpoint: /tracking/health

      location-mobile-health:
         image: mmg.ips.location-1.4.6.jar
         route_path: /location-mobile/**
         environment:
          - LOGGING_FILE: /dev/gtm/logs/location-mobile-health/location-mobile-health.log
         mem_limit: 128m
         restart: always
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I ran the code and it prints the changes to the console but it doesnt write it to the file. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I ran sed -Ei.bak "/tracking-service/n;s~(image: ).*~\1$newValue~" ./folder/fake.yml 0-i and got  sed: can't read 0-i: No such file or directory. I also noticed it changed both image: values. I need it to change only the one on tracking-service. thanks

Comment: @obumoon Whoops. Apologies. I have changed it. `sed -Ei.bak "/tracking-service/{n;s~(image: ).*~\1$newValue~}" file`